# Error creating a new SOLR Request Handler

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to make a query using SOLR Admin page:

I have defined a new SOLR Handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/globalmi-search-select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <int name="rows">10</int>
        <!-- ranking, boosting confiuration -->
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="qf">title^3.0 content^2.0 authors^1.0</str>
        <str name="df">text</str>
        <str name="fl">*,score</str>
        <str name="mm">3&lt;90% 6&lt;75%</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

But when I try to hit a * query on this handler, I get the below response:
[image]

Please let me know if i am missing anything.

Comment: Where have you made this change? Are you running in Solr Cloud or standalone mode? Have you reloaded the core / collection after making the change?

Comment: this is Solr Cloud

Comment: So where are you editing these files? Are you downloading and uploading them to your Zookeeper node through the downconfig/upconfig commands to `zkcli.sh`?

Comment: yes, I am downloading and uploading them to the Zookeeper node